# Не получается установить модуль discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, api, discord, pip, модули

Не получается установить модуль `discord.py`, через стандартное `pip install discord`, вывод консоли:

```
Collecting discord.py
  Using cached discord.py-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (701 kB)
Processing c:\users\errma\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b6\9c\bd\6b99bc6ec9dab11f3756d31fb8506d3ecf07aea58b6201f539\aiohttp-3.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-4.7.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.5.1.tar.gz (173 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting chardet<4.0,>=2.0
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict, yarl
  Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\errma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\errma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\errma\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgwpjmdr8'
       cwd: C:\Users\errma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jixzdf6a\multidict
  Complete output (40 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\errma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\errma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\errma\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpk83isfij'
       cwd: C:\Users\errma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jixzdf6a\yarl
  Complete output (35 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание на 5-ю с конца строку вывода.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Именно здесь указано, что именно не так. У вас не установлены средства компиляции Си-расширений для библиотек python. Вам нужен Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 или более поздней версии. Его можно получить, установив Microsoft C++ Build Tools. Ссылка именно не него и приведена в конце строки. Можете пройти по [этой ссылке](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) и установить BuildTools, после чего еще раз попробуйте переустановить библиотеку.